# In VBA, How to find a string in another sheet without exact match

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

using a variable I need to pick a value and store in variable "str" from sheet4 and search in sheet1. It has to find even it is not match exactly For example, If a str = "ABC123" then it is activate the cell in sheet1 which has the value "ABC12345"
I tried to with the below code,

```
Sub Find_First()
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
'Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
Set ws4 = Sheets("Export")

'FindString = InputBox("Enter a Search value")
FindString = ws4.Range("A1").Value
ws1.Activate
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False)


        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
        Else
            'MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: change `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart`

Comment: Also, while it doesn't fix your problem.. you should change `With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")` to `With ws1.Range("A:A")` for better reading/portability.

Comment: @CLR it is working as expected. Many thanks!!